# PyQGIS: How to load raster file from memory output

Tags: raster, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I have done raster processing in Step 1. Next, I want to do the second processing using the output raster from step 1. How do I load the output raster from step 1 and use it in Step 2?

My Code is as below:

```
   #STEP 1
   calc = processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator",
        {'INPUT_A':parameters[self.INPUT_RASTER],
         'BAND_A':1,
         'FORMULA': f'(A > {parameters[self.THRESHOLD]})',
         'OUTPUT':'memory:'
        },
        context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        index = calc['OUTPUT']
    
    #STEP 2 
    zonalhistogram = processing.run("native:zonalhistogram", 
        {'INPUT_RASTER':index,
         'RASTER_BAND':1,
         'INPUT_VECTOR':newcircle,
         'COLUMN_PREFIX':'HISTO_',
         'OUTPUT':'memory:'
        },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
         
    zonal_histo = zonalhistogram['OUTPUT']
```

It prompts this error:

```
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: Attempt to create new tiff file `memory:' failed: No error
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'
Process returned error code 1
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'output_64f8f0e4_c78f_4291_982d_5e19900c3325'}
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'output_dfc91a09_2b54_429d_9dd6_1af3a6fe1de8'}
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'output_ba93c7be_e7cc_4a6b_8ce3_62d154a50e02'}
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'output_28a99eb2_cb9c_4ef3_86c1_7b97057f13f7'}
Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT_RASTER: memory: not found
Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT_RASTER: memory: not found
Execution failed after 0.70 seconds
```

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `'OUTPUT':'memory:'`. To create a memory layer for the output of an intermediate processing step you should use either `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` or just `'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'`. Both of these will work because the attribute `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` just returns `QStringLiteral("TEMPORARY_OUTPUT")` as per [docs](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html#a62584b5ed1558ebdf04a95d6f4a9d403).

You can have a look at this script for a complete example based on your previous question. You can also see here how to use multi-step feedback in a parent algorithm which implements multiple calls to child algorithms and save outputs into a results dictionary which is returned at the end of the `ProcessAlgorithm()` method.

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
               QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
               QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
               QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
               QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer,
               QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
               QgsRasterLayer,
               QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback)
from qgis import processing

class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    THRESHOLD = 'THRESHOLD'
    ZONES = 'ZONES'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script with raster calc")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('NDVI Layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeRaster]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
            self.THRESHOLD,
            self.tr('Minimum Index'),
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.ZONES,
                self.tr('Vector Layer Containing Zones'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        outputs = {}
        results = {}
        
        steps = 2 # Number of child algorithms
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(steps, model_feedback)
        step = 1
        
        # Set current step and increment step counter for each child alg
        feedback.setCurrentStep(step)
        step+=1
        
        outputs['calc'] = processing.run('gdal:rastercalculator',
            {'INPUT_A':parameters[self.INPUT],
            'BAND_A':1,
            'FORMULA': f'(A > {parameters[self.THRESHOLD]})',
            'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
            },
            context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        
        results['calc'] = outputs['calc']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(step)
        step+=1
        
        #STEP 2 
        outputs['zonalhisto'] = processing.run("native:zonalhistogram", 
            {'INPUT_RASTER':results['calc'],
             'RASTER_BAND':1,
             'INPUT_VECTOR':parameters[self.ZONES],
             'COLUMN_PREFIX':'HISTO_',
             'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT]
            },context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
         
        results['zonalhisto'] = outputs['zonalhisto']['OUTPUT']

        return results
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem. May you live long and prosper :)

Comment: "Your problem is `'OUTPUT':'memory:'`" only a problem because this is a raster, right?